Response time for API request with "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" ON is taking less time than the one with this option OFF....How?
I was trying to assess one API for loading a dashboard. Strangely the same API request with "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" enabled is taking less time than if i uncheck this option for the same request. Am i missing something here or this is a probable scenario? Also the size of the data remains same in both cases. Usually the size should be higher in case of "Embedded resource" option enabled. Not sure what is going on over there. So am i missing something while enabling this option in the http request details



If you're testing an API you shouldn't enable this option.
In case of API you're getting XML or JSON without any "embedded resources" like images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.
JMeter spends extra time parsing the response and trying to extract embedded resources URLs from there.

Thanks for the clarification. But any idea on why the response time is varying. As you explained, for APIs checking/unchecking this embedded resources checkbox should not have any impact. But in the screenshot you can clearly see that checking this checkbox is taking less time than running the same with unchecking of the option.
